# How to get data from both tables in manytomany relationship?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have users and emails table. Each user have many email and each Email can have many users. I have users_email pivot table to query for data.

```
 $all=User::with('emails')->get();
```

The above query works fine but now I want to use WHERE clause to fetch a specific user with specific email. I've tried this so far but the result is unpredictable.

```
    $all=User::with(array('emails'=>function($query){
    $query->where('users.Id','=','78')->where('emails.Id','=','124');
    }))->first();
```

I expected to run this query but actually it doesn't

```
select * from users inner join users_email on
users.Id=user_email.Uid inner join email on
email.Id=user_email.email_id where email.Id=78
AND users.Id=45
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing a closure to `with()` will filter the eager loaded models but not change what `User` models are returned. For that you need `whereHas()`:

```
$all = User::with('emails')->whereHas('emails', function($query){
    $query->where('email_id','=','124');
})->get();
```

Comment: column not found emails.Id :(

Comment: Do you have an `Id` column in `emails`?

Comment: Yup and that is the primary key of my table

Comment: now that's working fine N I changed the query to to
 $all = User::with('emails')->whereHas('emails', function($query){
     $query->where('users_email.email_id','=','124')->where('users_email.Uid','=','78'); // or any other where condition
 })->first();
$all->email;//It prints email Id from users table but not message from email table
$all->message;

Comment: If you just want the email by id and it's message why don't you use `$email = Email::find(124); echo $email->message;`?

Comment: I want both user email address and email message body to be printed E.x
`$all->message;//email table contains message field
$all->email;//while this is email addres of user and users table contains this info` both are from different tables

Comment: Just run two queries: `$address = User::find(1)->email; $body = Email::find(1)->message;` Laravel's eager loading will need two queries anyways. You can also use the code from the question access the message like this: `$all->emails->first()->message`. But that brings you no advantage in my opinion.

Comment: This is not the solution to go with then I have to work with query builder join queries....! Running two queries isn't a good Idea while we have relationship there...!

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain-old inner-joins for this.  This query should give you all of the email addresses for the user id 78:

```
select * 
from users, user_email, email
where users.id=user_email.email_id and usermail.email_id=email.id
and users.id=45
```

Comment: I do not want to go with plain thing even I can do it with simple inner join..!